# Flutter asyncMap not run until setState

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am making a chat app that displays both a Group Chat and Private Chat in the same List.

I use Firestore as the database and store the data of User, Group and Contact in there. I have a Message Screen that displays a list of Chats that the User has using `StreamBuilder`.

I want to display data differently depending on the group's data. The group chat has their Group picture, Private Chat with User in Contact, their avatar display, and Private Chat with a generic icon display with User not in Contact.

I iterate through the stream first in a DatabaseService class, then put it in a variable and set it as a stream for `StreamBuilder`. This works fine, but I also want a list to check if a user already has a private chat with another User without getting the data from Firestore.

API.dart

```
//this is where I put my code to connect and read/write data from Firestore

final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

Api();

....

Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamCollectionByArrayAny(
      String path, String field, dynamic condition) {
    return _db
        .collection(path)
        .where(field, arrayContainsAny: condition)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

DatabaseService.dart

```
...
List<GroupModel> groups; //List of Groups
Stream<List<GroupModel>> groupStream; //Stream of List Group
...
Stream<QuerySnapshot> fetchGroupsByMemberArrayAsStream(
      String field, dynamic condition) {
    return _api.streamCollectionByArrayAny('groups', field, condition);
  }
//function to get Contact Detail using List of Group User
Future<ContactModel> getContactDetail(List<dynamic> members) async {

    //remove current user id from the list
    members.removeWhere((element) => element.userId == user.userId);

    //getContactbyId return a ContactModel object from Firestore
    ContactModel contactModel =
        await getContactById(user.userId, members.first.userId);

    if (contactModel != null && contactModel.userId.isNotEmpty) {
      return contactModel;
    } else {
      return new ContactModel(
          userId: members.first.userId, nickname: "", photoUrl: "");
    }
  }

  Future<GroupModel> generateGroupMessage(GroupModel group) async {

    //check if Group Chat or Private chat
    if (group.type == 1) {
      ContactModel contactModel = await getContactDetail(group.membersList);
      group.groupName = contactModel.nickname.isNotEmpty
          ? contactModel.nickname
          : contactModel.userId;
      group.groupPhoto = contactModel.photoUrl;
    }
    print("Add");
    
    //add the group data into List<GroupModel> groups
    groups.add(group);
    return group;
  }

  void refreshMessageList() {
    groups = [];
    print("refresh");

    //get Group Data as Stream from FireStore base on the user data in the Member Array of Group then map it to Stream while also change data base on Group type in generateGroupMessage
    groupStream = fetchGroupsByMemberArrayAsStream('membersList', [
      {"isActive": true, "role": 1, "userId": user.userId},
      {"isActive": true, "role": 2, "userId": user.userId}
    ]).asyncMap((docs) => Future.wait([
          for (GroupModel group in docs.docs
              .map((doc) => GroupModel.fromMap(doc.data()))
              .toList())
            generateGroupMessage(group)
        ]));
  }
```

Message.dart

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ...
    databaseService.refreshMessageList();
    setState(() {});
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
        child: Column(
          children: [
          ...
          Flexible(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: databaseService.groupStream,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<GroupModel>> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    print("No data");
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    print("Has data");
                    groups = List.from(snapshot.data);
                    groups.removeWhere(
                        (element) => element.recentMessageContent.isEmpty);
                    groups.sort((group1, group2) {
                      if (DateTime.parse(group1.recentMessageTime)
                          .isAfter(DateTime.parse(group2.recentMessageTime))) {
                        return -1;
                      } else {
                        return 1;
                      }
                    });
                    return ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                            buildItem(context, groups[index]),
                        itemCount: groups.length,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                }
  ],)));
}

Widget buildItem(BuildContext context, GroupModel group) {
    if (group.recentMessageContent == '') {
      return Container();
    } else {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: InkWell(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Material(
                      child: group.groupPhoto.isNotEmpty
                          ? CachedNetworkImage(
                              placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  strokeWidth: 1.0,
                                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                      Colors.grey),
                                ),
                                width: 60.0,
                                height: 60.0,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              ),
                              imageUrl: group.groupPhoto,
                              width: 60.0,
                              height: 60.0,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            )
                          : Icon(
                              group.type == 1
                                  ? Icons.account_circle
                                  : Icons.group,
                              size: 60.0,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 150,
                      child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              group.groupName,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: colorBlack,
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              group.recentMessageContent,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontSize: 10,
                                  height: 1.6),
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text(
                      formatDateTime(group.recentMessageTime),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  switch (group.type) {
                    case 1:
                      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              settings:
                                  RouteSettings(name: "/message/chatPage"),
                              builder: (context) => ChatPage(group: group)))
                          .then((value) => setState);
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              settings:
                                  RouteSettings(name: "/message/chatGroup"),
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  ChatGroupPage(group: group)))
                          .then((value) => {setState(() {})});
                      break;
                  }
                }),
          ),
          Divider(
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
```

The `ChatPage` and `ChatGroupPage` navigate to Private Chat and Group Chat respectively, and in there the User can add the chat partner or group member into Contact.

When adding is done I call the `databaseService.refreshMessageList` to refresh the Stream of List Group, so when I navigate back to the Message Screen, it will refresh and display accordingly. However, the `List<GroupModel>` groups becomes blank and will not add data until I navigate back to the Message Screen.

I debugged the app and found that the List became blank because it executes groups = [] but did not run the `.asyncMap` until I hot reload or navigate Message Screen and put the `setState` in  .then to refresh the data.

I need the List groups to check whether the 2 users already have a private chat to create a new one when adding to Contact. I have already tried putting `setState` after `databaseService.refreshMessageList`, but it still did not work.

Can anyone please help me and provide a solution? I know this is not a good question to ask, but I have been stuck with this for almost a week now and desperately need an answer. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is my data structure:

Users

```
/users (collection)
    /userId
        /user (document)
        - userId
        - nickname
        - photoUrl
        - token
        - /contacts (subcollection)
              /contactId
                  /contact (document)
                  - userId
                  - nickname
                  - photoUrl
```

Groups:

```
/groups (collection)
    /groupId
        /group (document)
        - groupId
        - groupName
        - type
        - membersList (List<Map<String, dynamic>>)
              - member: userId, isActive, role
        - recentMessageContent
        - recentMessageTime
        - recentMessageType
```

Messages:

```
/messages (collection)
    /groupId
        /groupMessage (document)
             /messages (subcollection)
                  /messageId
                       /message (document)
                       - messageContent
                       - messageTime
                       - messageType
```

Comment: Can you also add your data structure to the question? it will be helpful to understand your configuration.

Comment: Sure, I have added it in the question. Please have a look if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), for example, the `array-contains` method can query for elements within an array without performing any manipulation. There is an interesting [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html) that provides some examples you might interest you.

Another alternative could be to iterate both arrays until matching the values you need. However, iteration can lead to [performance issues](https://medium.com/better-programming/which-is-the-fastest-while-for-foreach-for-of-9022902be15e) if you do not implement it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not sure how this will solve my problem. My problem seems to be that the ````.asyncMap```` does not run until there is a reload by setState or manual hot reload but it does not run until I back out of the ````ChatPage```` to the ````Messages```` screen. The ````fetchGroupsByMemberArrayAsStream```` already stream data back as QuerySnapshots using ````array-contains````, because my membersList array contains map in it, I provided the full map data, e.g. ````{"isActive": true, "role": 2, "userId": user.userId}```` for it to search, so using it isn't a prob

Comment: I could not see the `array-contains` in the `fetchGroupsByMemberArrayAsStream` code snippet you have provided. Have you managed to get this to work? It would be interesting to see where the issue is.

Comment: You might find this link on [Debugging Flutter Apps helpful](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging)

Comment: I have not but I was able to add data into ````group```` array by splitting the function in ````.asyncMap```` into another function and put the ````addGroup```` there for it to populate the ````group```` array. When I run the debugger and execute the ````refreshMessageList```` function in the ChatPage, I put the breakpoint on all of the function line and saw that it execute the ````fetchGroupsByMemberArrayAsStream```` but not the .asyncMap after that and only when I navigate back to ````messagePage```` where I put the setState in ````.then```` did it continue to run the .asyncMap.

Comment: I will update the code to include the ````fetchGroupsByMemberArrayAsStream```` exact code